# Append but not add to $PATH

Tags: python

I'm working with 16.04.2 LTS. I've added miniconda to allow me to get access to python3.6 ( The system python is 3.5 ). I changed my .bashrc by adding

```
export PATH=~/miniconda3/bin:$PATH
alias python3.6='/home/deploy/miniconda3/bin/python3.6'
```

However I notice that:

```
deploy@server:~$ python -V
Python 3.6.0 :: Continuum Analytics, Inc.
```

Checking $PATH I see:

```
deploy@server:~$ echo $PATH
/home/deploy/bin:/home/deploy/.local/bin:/home/deploy/miniconda3/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games
```

So I think that I am causing the system to take the first python it finds (miniconda 3.6), instead of the native 3.5 version. How can I change my .bashrc to APPEND instead of add the path so I assume it will go back to using the native version?

Comment: Recommendation: quote your `PATH` assignment, as in `PATH="~/miniconda3/bin:$PATH"`, to avoid word splitting if there are paths that have whitespace. Overall, just get used to always quoting shell variables

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you are creating an alias to `python3.6` then there is no need to add it to your `PATH` unless there are some other utilities in that path which you want to have access them using `bash`.

If that's the case then in your `.bashrc` use something like:

```
export PATH=$PATH:~/miniconda3/bin
```

it will put your `~/miniconda3/bin` at the end of PATH environment variable so your native applications will not be overridden.

Comment: Thanks yes I need the conda command to be available. Also does the ':' mean add to/concatenate with?

Comment: It's just a separator... `path1:path2:...`